# Receive Url in Cordova/Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

i want to receive a url from other apps like facebooks or youtube in my cordova apps. I view this:

- [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/webintent/)
- [plugins](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent)

i install the plugins  and then i write this piece of code.

```
window.plugins.webintent.hasExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT,
    function(url) {
        // url is the value of EXTRA_TEXT
    }, function() {
        // Something really bad happened.
    }
);
```

I use cordova/ionic with typescript
I've some question:
first : where i put this piece of code?in a method?in the constructor?
second : i have this error -> property plugins does not exist on type windows

EDIT:
This is the constructor

```
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      WebIntent.hasExtra(WebIntent.EXTRA_TEXT).then(
        function(url) {
    console.log("succes" + url);
  }, function(url) {
      console.log("error" + url)
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: are you still getting the error?

Comment: no, i haven't error, but when i am in youtube and i click the share button my app it isn't in the list

Comment: could tell if you put some code..

Comment: i add the constructor

Comment: you need to start the activity first `WebIntent.startActivity({ action: any, url: string }).then().catch()`

Comment: read through the docs..

Comment: sorry, in the .then() i put the webIntent.hasExtra...?i have no idea

Comment: yeah.. you could do that.

Comment: but i have no idea what to pu in the url parameters.. can we erite it together?

Comment: you will have to figure it out..if you are stuck with a specific issue..just put a question in Stack overflow

Comment: i edit the answer

Comment: i open another answer, please view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332300/cordova-ionic2-receive-data-from-other-apps

Answer (score 2):

If you have used ionic-native ,according to the docs

```
import {WebIntent} from 'ionic-native';

WebIntent.hasExtra(WebIntent.EXTRA_TEXT).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

You can use it after

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
//use plugin
})
```

Comment: Where are you using it? the hasExtra function

Comment: the code in my post work only at startup, he print in console false. If i try to re-share it doesnt'work,  there is nothing in my console

Comment: it is correct to put thi code in the constructor of my home.ts?

Comment: no, nothing is change. There is an working example in ionic2 with typescript?i've search everywhere!!

Comment: I am running out of ideas too..check out https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks the part about custom url scheme here looks like what you are looking for

Comment: i see this, but the don't says how to receive data